# MATLAB dynamically read/write attributes - getattr, setattr?

Tags: matlab

```py
class A(): pass
a = A()
setattr(a, 'dog', True)
```

Is there a MATLAB equivalent? If not, what's the most compact alternative? Currently I do

```matlab
for i=1:length(keys)
    k = keys{i};
    v = values{i};
    if k == "arg1"
        obj.arg1 = v;
    elseif k == "arg2"
        obj.arg2 = v;
    ...
```

Likewise for `getattr`? If needed, assume all `keys` are already `Properties`.

Non-Python readers: `setattr(obj, 'a', 1) <=> obj.a = 1` and `getattr(obj, 'a') <=> obj.a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj.arg1` is the same as `obj.('arg1')`.

So in your code snippet is equivalent to:

```
for i=1:length(keys)
   obj.(keys{i}) = values{i};
end
```

Comment: Should be in front page docs!